# python different result from IDLE and python script

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, nltk, tokenize

I have tried the following in Python 2.7 shell:

```
  >>> from nltk.stem.isri import ISRIStemmer
  >>> st = ISRIStemmer()
  >>> string = u'\u062D\u064E\u062F\u0651\u064E\u062B\u064E\u0646\u064E\u0627'
  >>> st.stem(string)
      u'\u062d\u062f\u062b'
```

So basically, I am trying to obtain:

```
u'\u062d\u062f\u062b'
```

from

```
u'\u062D\u064E\u062F\u0651\u064E\u062B\u064E\u0646\u064E\u0627'
```

using nltk's arabic stemmer, which works!

However, when I try to accomplish the exact thing through a python script, it fails to stem any of the words in the list, `tokens` :

```
#!/c/Python27/python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import nltk
import nltk.data
from nltk.stem.isri import ISRIStemmer

#In my script, I tokenize the following string
commasection = '\u0623\u064E\u062E\u0652\u0628\u064E\u0631\u064E\u0646\u064E\u0627 \u0628\u0650\u0634\u0652\u0631\u064F \u0628\u0652\u0646\u064F \u0647\u0650\u0644\u0627\u064E\u0644\u064D'

#The tokenizing works
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(commasection)
st = ISRIStemmer()

for word in tokens:
    #But the stemming of each word in tokens doesn't work????
    print st.stem(word)

    #Should display 
    #u'u0623\u062e\u0628\u0631'
    #u'\u0628\u0634\u0631'
    #u'\u0628\u0646'
    #u'\u0647\u0644\u0644'

    #But it just shows whatever is in commasection
```

I need my python code to stem all words in `tokens`. But I don't get how the simpler example running in python shell works but not this script.

I have noticed that in the shell scenario, there is that 'u' in front of the sequence of unicode, so I tried all sorts of encodings/decodings and read a lot about it all night long (pulled an all-nighter on this one), but this python script is just not stemming `word` from `tokens` like the python shell!!!

If anyone can please help me make my script display the correct result I would be super super appreciative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignacio is correct that I have to have unicode literals in order for the stemming to work, but since I am grabbing this string dynamically, I had to find a way to convert what I get dynamically

i.e. `'\u0623\u064E\u062E\u0652\u0628\u064E\u0631\u064E\u0646\u064E\u0627 \u0628\u0650\u0634\u0652\u0631\u064F \u0628\u0652\u0646\u064F \u0647\u0650\u0644\u0627\u064E\u0644\u064D'`

into a string literal with a unicode escapes i.e. 
`u'\u0623\u064E\u062E\u0652\u0628\u064E\u0631\u064E\u0646\u064E\u0627 \u0628\u0650\u0634\u0652\u0631\u064F \u0628\u0652\u0646\u064F \u0647\u0650\u0644\u0627\u064E\u0644\u064D'`

(notice the `u` in front)

This can be done with the following unichr() http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/python/web/unichr-function.html:

`word = "".join([unichr(int(x, 16)) for x in word.split("\\u") if x !=""])`

So basically I grab the numeric codes and form the unicode character while maintaining the unicode escape. And my stemmer works!

Comment: Congrats for solving the problem! If @Ignacio's answer doesn't amount to a solution, you can (and are encouraged to) accept your own answer, to indicate to others that it contains the solution to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Unicode escapes only work in `unicode` literals.

```
commasection = u'\u0623\u064E\u062E\u0652\u0628\u064E\u0631\u064E\u0646\u064E\u0627 \u0628\u0650\u0634\u0652\u0631\u064F \u0628\u0652\u0646\u064F \u0647\u0650\u0644\u0627\u064E\u0644\u064D'
```

Comment: The thing is that I am grabbing `commasection` from a list called `sentence`. Would there be a way to turn an item that is string from a list into a literal?

Comment: You're going to need to show how you get your data then.

Comment: Ok so in my script `sentence` holds a long string of unicodes. And  `commasection` is an item in the list `sentence.split('\u060C')`. If `commasection` were to be printed out: '\u0623\u064E\u062E\u...' Based on your answer, my question is, is it possible turn `commasection` into unicode literal as it is dynamically getting its data from `sentence`?

Comment: You can try using commasection.decode('utf-8','ignore') dynamically. The problem is that re.split('\u060C') turns the whole sentence into ASCII since that's how regex module works in Python. I suppose you can try decoding before applying the split function or else try to play with defining overall encoding for your script by # -*-coding: utf-8-*- at the header.